# Web services vs Socket programming

Tags: java, web-services, sockets

I need to design for searching for a file application in Java. I have planned to design it with

1. Socket
2. Web services with javaws

Which is faster in application which searches for file from a distributed system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with option 2.

Primary Reasons

1. Less coupling between client and server
2. Ability to scale
3. Ability to incrementally add new apis
4. Pre-built libraries that will help you get this done fast.

Comment: Not really an answer to "Which is faster?", unless you meant that #4 means faster to develop, but I believe OP was asking about runtime performance.

Comment: Agree this approach will be slower because of the http overhead, but I'd guess that's a premature optimization problem. Assuming that the OP wants to build a REST service.

Comment: Yeah, the "search for file" performance, as well as the network speed, will likely outweigh any performance impact of the actual transport *protocol*.